# Disable Cyanogen 10.1 notification drawer widgets

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications

I want to remove the notification drawer widgets, but despite having `System > Notification Drawer > Power Widget` unchecked, it keeps showing up.

When I have *new* notifications, pulling down the drawer reveals them; but if I do it a second time, without any *unseen* items, I'm treated to a screenful of widgets I don't really need and have to manually switch back to the notifications list.

How can I disable this, and have a plain old notifications dropdown?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the "Quick Settings panel", which is different (and actually a feature of vanilla Android Jelly Bean). Try `System > Quick Settings panel > Quick pulldown > Off`. Or possibly provide a screenshot if you can, to make sure we're talking about the same set of notification bar toggles, since CM 10.1 has two.

Comment: Indeeeeeeed! Given 10 years I would've never realized it was showing up when I pulled the status bar FROM THE RIGHT EDGE. Move the comment to an answer, and accepted it will get

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn you can get it if you do a 2-finger pull-down too, how many years would it take anyone to notice that without being told about it!

Comment: @GAThrawn more years than the feature is going to last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to sum up the bit of confusion that is in CM 10.1 now - there are actually *two* sets of notification bar toggles. One works like the old set from previous CM versions, and it appears in one row above your notifications when you pull down the bar. These are the "Power Widget" toggles.

The second set was a feature added upstream in Jelly Bean, and is referred to as the "Quick Settings panel". These are laid out as multi-row tiles - which it sounds like you are describing - and you can switch to this view by tapping the top right icon on your notifications shade (after pulling it down):

[image]

You cannot, to my knowledge, get rid of the Quick Settings panel completely, as it is baked in to Android. However, you can prevent it from appearing of its own accord by going into

```
Settings > System > Quick Settings panel > Quick pulldown
```

and selecting the "Off" option. The other options are "Right" and "Left", with the idea being that you can basically divide the notification pulldown into two swipe areas if you like. For instance, by choosing "Right", you can access your notifications by pulling down from the left side of the bar, and access the Quick Settings panel by pulling down from the right side of the bar. If you choose "Off" then the only way to get to the Quick Settings panel should be if you pull down your notifications and then tap the icon in the top right. Effectively, this disables the Quick Settings panel from ever appearing unless you explicitly choose to see it.